# Is it possible to realize AJAX with some absolute url form same domain?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web

I have:
page, which include javaScript code place in URL *site.com/index/user*
but I want to send ajax request to URL: *site.com/php/myscript.php*,  so can I use absolute url for this? Or how can I send request with relative URL?

Comment: Restrictions only apply when trying to access other domain's contents. As long as it's the same domain, use relative or absolute paths just like you wish to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both relative and absolute URLs when sending ajax requests - they will be resolved to the same location. Of course, [SOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) stays in place, but it looks like your case doesn't conflict with it anyway.